# Make make rebuild a target when it depends on a deleted file

Tags: makefile, incremental-build

Suppose I have a `make` rule like this:

```
SOURCES := $(wildcard ./text/*.txt)

$(INDEX) : $(SOURCES)
    $(COMPILER) $(SOURCES)
```

And then one of the text files, `./text/foo.txt`, is deleted. The target `$(INDEX)` does not seem to be rebuilt. How do I make `make` rebuild in this case?

Comment: So you want to maintain a list of required sources. In this scenario, do you want Make to update the list (and therefore not require that missing file next time)? What if a new source file appears, do you want Make to add it to the list (and therefore require it next time)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `./text` directory contains only your sources and all of them, you can add it as a pre-requisite of your target:

```
$(INDEX) : $(SOURCES) ./text
```

Directories are not like regular files: their last modification date is updated when you add, delete or rename a file (or subdirectory) in them, not when an existing file is modified. Think of it as a file containing the list of contained files.